Cannot connect to raspberry pi 4 via ssh (first time installation)
I am a complete newbie and installing Raspberry Pi OS on my Raspberry Pi 4 for the first time. I follow the standard approach, I use a linux PC (Ubuntu 23.04) and installed an imager there, and installed the OS onto my microSD via the imager.
Used the recommended installation of 64bit OS with desktop environment. I also enabled SSH with the settings before installation with username@raspberry.pi host name
Now I do not have access to a monitor, so I am trying to connect to RPI via SSH (after inserting the microSD in RPI and powering it).
ssh username@raspberrypi.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
ssh username@raspberrypi
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Temporary failure in name resolution
I try to find the IP address of the RPI via
ifconfig
and this is what I get:
enp1s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 74:5d:XX:XX:XX:d9 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 2499 bytes 301911 (301.9 KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 2499 bytes 301911 (301.9 KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1456
inet 192.XXX.XXX.XX netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.XXX.XXX.XXX
inet6 ..... prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 .... prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 .... prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 04:7b:cb:c5:24:14 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 50927 bytes 52979390 (52.9 MB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 20925 bytes 8521567 (8.5 MB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

Contrary to what I see in forums, I do not find a WLAN0 inet, and I believe the wlp2s0 corresponds to my wifi router.
Similarly,
Code: Select all
arp -a
renders only the wifi IP and not the raspberry pi IP.
I'm lost. I unfortunately do not also have access to the router (It's a communal router), nor an ethernet cable. I do not know what the problem is and how to fix it. I have tried the fresh installation multiple times and the problem persists! Any help is appreciated.

You have failed to explain (in detail) how you "Used the recommended installation of 64bit OS with desktop environment. I also enabled SSH with the settings before installation with username@raspberry.pi host name"
I assume you are trying to setup the Pi to wirelessly connect to the router.
If you preconfigure during the imaging process you can set the hostname, user/password, Locale, wireless networking and enable ssh BUT you still need to boot the Pi to complete the setup process then reboot. It IS possible to do headless (if you get everything right - particularly the locale, i.e. country code without which WiFi will not work) but using Ethernet or a monitor is easier.
username@raspberry.pi is NOT the same as ssh username@raspberrypi and you should use ssh username@hostname.local
See How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm
It is pointless trying to obscure private IP addresses inet 192.XXX.XXX.XX and just makes it more difficult to work out what you have.
"Contrary to what I see in forums, I do not find a WLAN0 inet, and I believe the wlp2s0 corresponds to my wifi router" what you have listed (presumably on your linux PC) says NOTHING about the Pi - it is the PC setting.
If you connect your Pi to the Ubuntu system with an Ethernet cable you should be able to ssh into it.
